# user-defined literals overloading in <chrono>

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, user-defined-literals

chrono  takes user-defined literals to make it more convenient. For each literal, it has two overloading functions.

```
constexpr chrono::hours operator "" h(unsigned long long);
constexpr chrono::duration<unspecified , ratio<3600,1>> operator "" h(long double);
```

I'm confused by the second overloading function, i.e. the function with `long double` as parameter.

Why we need the second overloading? And what is `unspecified`?

Comment: See [this documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator""h) for why the two overloads exist. As for the `unspecified` it is **implementation defined**

Comment: This is the exact answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Both](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22h) represent [std::chrono::duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) in hours. The first one forms an integer literal, the second one forms a floating-point literal. First one can represent tick count only, the second one can represent fractions of ticks.